# Saving a Value, and adding to it

Tags: javascript, html

There are a few ways this can be asked, I'm trying to go with the easiest. Basically, I have two fields... one is to add a number, the other is to subtract. What I want, is when a number is input into either (let's just stick with the add input for now) and have it update at the bottom once the button "+" is pressed. I want that result to stay at the bottom, so when a new value is put into the add box and the button is pressed, it ADDS to the previous total. For the life of me, I can't figure this one out. Once resolved, I'll take care of the subtraction on my own, just need a push in the right direction. The current code is as follows.

```
<div id="entire">
  <div id="content">
    <input type="number" id="addInput" placeholder="0">
    <button type="button" id="addBtn" onclick="add()">+</button>
    <br>
    <br> 
    <input type="number" id="subInput" placeholder="0">
    <button type="button" id="subBtn" onclick="sub()">-</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="totalAmt"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearFields()" value="Clear">

    <input type="button" id="reset" onclick="reset()" value="Reset">
  </div>
</div>

function add() {
  var addInput = document.getElementById("addInput").value;
  var emptyValue = "";
  var total = emptyValue + addInput;
  document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML = total;
}

function clearFields() {
  document.getElementById("addInput").value = "";
  document.getElementById("subInput").value = "";
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML = "";
}
```

A link to my codepen is below:

http://codepen.io/0ktane/pen/NNdbOq

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is these two lines

```
var emptyValue = "";
var total = emptyValue + addInput;
```

when you are concatenating to a string, you get a string back.

Also, you are not even considering the previous value at first place.

Try this, updated [pen](http://codepen.io/gurvinder372/pen/qZRRNL)

```
function add() {
  var addInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("addInput").value); //parse the value to an integer first
  var totalAmt = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML); //parse the value to an integer first
  totalAmt = isNaN(totalAmt) ? 0 : totalAmt; //if the value is NaN(not a number) reset it to 0
  addInput = isNaN(addInput) ? 0 : addInput;//if the value is NaN(not a number) reset it to 0
  document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML = totalAmt + addInput ; //output the correct value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
function add() {
  var addInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("addInput").value);
  total = total + addInput;
  document.getElementById("totalAmt").innerHTML = total;
}
```